# List requires a type argument

Tags: c#, list, oop, object-oriented-analysis

There are three errors while compiling the code.
1.Using the generic type List requires 1 argument.
2.Using the generic type List requires 1 argument.
3. foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type because List does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

The program of Polymorphism example is below.

```
namespace PolymorExample
{
    abstract class Shape
    {
        public abstract void area();
    }

    class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        private double length;
        private double width;

        public Rectangle(double length, double width)
        {
            this.length = length;
            this.width = width;
        }

        public override void area()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Rectangel Area: {0}", length * width);
        }
    }

    class Triangle : Shape
    {
        private double baseline;
        private double height;

        public Triangle(double baseline, double height)
        {
            this.baseline = baseline;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public override void area()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Triangel Area: {0}", baseline * height / 2.0);
        }
    }

    class Circle : Shape
    {
        const double PI = 3.14;
        private double radius;

        public Circle(double radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public override void area()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Circle Area: {0}", radius * radius * PI);
        }
    }

    public class TestShape
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List shapes = new List();
            Shape shape1 = new Rectangle(10, 10);
            shapes.Add(shape1);
            shapes.Add(new Circle(10));
            shapes.Add(new Triangle(10, 10));
            shapes.Add(new Circle(20));

            foreach (Shape s in shapes)
            {
                s.area();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `List<Shape>`.

Comment: As far as I know there is no _non-generic_ `List` type in the .NET Framework.  You would have to specify a type argument: `List<Shape>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for the [`List<T>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), you'll notice that `List` is a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) type (hence the `<T>`), and generic types require a parameter (or more) that specifies the type(s) of object it will use/contain. You must specify *some* type, even if it's just `object`.

In your case, you have a list of `Shape` objects, so your initialization code can be modified (and simplified by using collection initializer syntax) to specify that type:

```
var shapes = new List<Shape>
{
    new Rectangle(10, 10),
    new Circle(10),
    new Triangle(10, 10),
    new Circle(20)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
```

you need the shape type in your list declaration so it knows what its a list of